# Copying Visual Studio projects out of TFS and Git without retaining source control information

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I would like to use File Explorer to take a purely local copy of some Visual Studio projects that are currently under source control (under both TFS and Git). Once I have copied the project folders outside of the mapped folder hierarchy which files and folders do I need to remove from the copied directories in order to remove the Visual Studio source control information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different files and folders used for the two different source control technologies.

### TFS

Remove all the files `*.vssscc` and `*.vspscc`.

### Git

Remove all the files `.gitignore` and all the sub-directories `.git`. To see the latter you may have to check "Show hidden files, folders, and drives" in the view tab of Folder Options in the Control Panel.

Comment: There is also the $tf folder if you have TFS local workspaces

Answer (score 1):

My solution was using TFS and I had to edit the .sln file and remove the the TeamFoundationServer global section.

I removed everything from the `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)` line to the next `EndGlobalSection`